# Defining seperate iteration (sprint) sets for teams within a project

Tags: azure-devops

So after setting up my teams, I need to define separate sprints for each.  I notice that when I go under project settings > work > iterations, I see the default set defined for a new project.  The name that these default iterations fall under is the same name as the project.  So that leads me to ask
- Is the name Im looking at for a new project that has these default iterations, the name of the project or the default team?

In other words, Im looking at setting up my team/iteration structure like this, is there a better or best-practice approach (when using multiple teams within a single team project) ?

Below, I defined new children of the root node (again, is that the project name or default team with the same name?)

```
root-name-here
 |__Team1
    |__Sprint1
    |__Sprint2
    |__Sprint3
    |__Sprint4  
    |__Sprint5
    |__Sprint6
 |__Team2
    |__Sprint1
    |__Sprint2
    |__Sprint3
    |__Sprint4  
    |__Sprint5
    |__Sprint6
|__Sprint1
|__Sprint2
|__Sprint3
|__Sprint4  
|__Sprint5
|__Sprint6
```

The "default" set of iterations that are now at the same level, can I simply remove them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can config different iterations based on different teams. Detail as below:

PS: I share the steps with New Navigation, if you want to turn on the New Navigation, set as below:
Click profile -> Preview features -> then turn on the New Navigation).

#### 1.   Add iterations with the structure you need

In Project settings -> Project configurations -> Iterations Tab -> Add iterations as below (as you listed):

[image]

#### 2.   Specify different iterations for different teams

In Project settings -> Team configurations -> select different iterations for different teams. Besides, you can also set default iteration and backlog iteration for different teams.

Such as:

- Select `Git2\Sprint 1~6` to `Git2 Team`:

  [image]
- Select `Git2\team 1\Sprint 1~6` to `teamA`:

  [image]
- Select `Git2\team 2\Sprint 1~6` to `second` team:

  [image]

Now when open backlogs for different teams, only the specified iterations are listed.

Answer (score 1):

You can define the overall iterations for the project at the project level.

At the team level, you set the team's backlog iteration and what sprints belong to that team.

If the project level iteration is just for rolling up the progress of the individual teams, then yes, you can remove the project level iterations.

Comment: So in my example, the "root-name-here" that is seen with a default project, will correspond to the team-project level as opposed to the default team?

Comment: The default team **is** the one defined at the team project level, unless you've changed it.

Comment: Im speaking only about the iterations that are seen for a new project, and the name that is seen containing the iterations.  That top level node, does that correspond to the default team or the team project level.  Im guessing it corresponds to the team project itself.  That sorta makes sense.  This would let you assign different teams to different sprints, each with their own timeline.